# How to compare row with subquery output in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

There are two tables, OrderID and Order Details.

Orders:

```
OrderID PK
Freight
|....|
```

Order Details:

```
OrderID PK FK
ProductID PK FK
UnitPrice
Quantity
|....|
```

Each `OrderID` is unique for `Orders`, but Order Details can contain several details for the same `OrderID` and different `ProductId`, `UnitPrice` etc.

So, in Order Details we can see two, three or more orders (`OrderID`).

My task is to select physical addresses of all Freight records which more than total cost of entire order Freight > UnitPrice * Quantity * (Quantity of OrderID in Order Details)

```
SELECT %%physloc%%
FROM Orders
WHERE Freight > (SELECT SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity)
                 FROM [Order Details]
                 GROUP BY OrderID);
```

And of course I've got

> 'Subquery returned more than 1 value...'

I try to use Top but in that case I have a wrong selection.

All that I need is to compare somehow each Freight with OrderID records with each records from that subquery with same OrderID. But I have no idea how.

Maybe someone can find a different way, It would be great.

I use SQL Server 2008

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My task is to select physical addresses of all Freight records which more than total cost of entire order Freight > UnitPrice * Quantity * (Quantity of OrderID in Order Details)

You can achieve that easily by using aliases and filtering the subquery in the following way...

```
SELECT %%physloc%%
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.Freight > (SELECT SUM(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity)
                 FROM [Order Details] as od
                 WHERE od.OrderId = o.OrderId);
```

You don't need a `group by` clause here at all because it could potentially split/group the results. By using the `sum` aggregate function you're already returning a scalar value which can further be filtered by a `where` clause

Comment: So simple. Why I hadn't thought of it? Anyway, now, with your help, my eyes open. I sending you a plenty of rays of goodness :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of thinking of the process is as follows:

1. The outer query processes each record within the Orders table. As this happens, the current OrderID is shared with the subquery. This is made possible by the subquery's "where" statement.  This will ensure the data being summed in the subquery has the same OrderID.
2. The use of *aliases* makes referencing tables much easier than having to specify the full name of each table and its corresponding column. Format: tableName.Column e.g. Orders.OrderID. The much easier alternative alias.Column e.g. o.OrderID where "o" is defined as an alias of Orders.

---

```
SELECT %%physloc%%
FROM Orders o
WHERE Freight > (SELECT SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity)
                 FROM [Order Details] od
                 WHERE od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    GROUP BY OrderID);
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank's a lot. I knew about aliases but in code in my question I just don't feel that aliases is necessary. However, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should just join to the query you want to use as such.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM Orders as o
INNER JOIN (SELECT od.OrderId, SUM(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) as Total
            FROM Details as od
            GROUP BY od.OrderId) as d ON d.orderId = o.Id
WHERE o.Freight > d.Total;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a151f/6

edit:

Also note that you have OrderId as the primary key on the Orders table, this is usually annotation for foreign keys.

Comment: The code needs a minor tweak to remain consistent with OPs data scheme o.id should be switched to o.orderid

Comment: Well, sure, but I think the tables primary key shouldn't be named like it appears to be a FK. hence the Id instead of OrderId in the Orders table.

Comment: Thank you, your way show me how to think a little different =)